# What's the theoretical basis of sampling ols regression coefficients from a multivariate $t$-distribution instead of a multivariate normal?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, simulation

In their 2000 [paper](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/making.pdf) "Making the Most of Statistical Analyses: Improving Interpretation and Presentation", Gary King et al. present a method of using simulation to compute quantities of interest and their uncertainties.

As an example: Assume that we want to calculate an approximate 95% confidence interval for the inflection point of a 3rd order polynomial regression function $y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \beta_3 x^3$ ($\beta_3\neq 0)$. The point estimate of the inflection point is $-\frac{\beta_{2}}{3\beta_{3}}$. To calculate a confidence interval, we could do the following steps according to the paper:

1. Estimate the model using ols. Store the coefficient estimates and covariance matrix.
2. Sample $n$ coefficient vectors from a multivariate normal distribution with the mean vector and covariance matrix equal to their estimated values from step 1.
3. For each of the $n$ draws, calculate the inflection point.
4. Take the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of the $n$ calculated inflection points from step 3 to get a 95% confidence interval for the inflection point.

These steps are implemented in the [`clarify`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=clarify) package for R. However, the [help page](https://rdrr.io/cran/clarify/man/sim.html) for `sim` (the function that does the sampling) suggests that for ols models, the coefficients are drawn from a multivariate $t$ distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the residual degrees of freedom.

**Question:** What's the theoretical basis to sample the regression coefficients from a multivariate $t$ distribution instead of a multivariate normal? I can't find a justification of this in the papers.

Standard textbooks note that if $Y\sim\operatorname{N}_n(\mathbf{X}\beta,\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_n)$ then $\hat{\beta}\sim \operatorname{N}_p(\beta, \sigma^2(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1})$ (e.g. Seber & Lee 2003, p. 47). So under the assumption that the errors are normally distributed, the coefficients have a multivariate normal sampling distribution.

Comment: intro to linear models textbooks will have this kind of info. personally, I'm partial to Graybill.

Comment: Multivariate $t$ is supposedly more robust to outliers than multivariate normal, although the empirical relevance of this claim [has been disputed](https://doi.org/10.1111/1467-9574.00055).